# Permission access to microphone of iOS device ios

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, xcode, permissions

I want **permission access to Microphone of iOS device.** Project is in Angular JS 1 and android team had written native code to access microphone which works perfectly fine. Below is native code for Android

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

What will be equivalent code for iOS? Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking for `js` code or native iOS?

Comment: @Ivan : Mentioned in question itself I'm looking for equivalent code for iOS.

Comment: Friends, why down vote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]First of all add "Privacy - Microphone Usage Description" property in your info.plist.
Than add following code ==>

fow swift =>

```
import AVFoundation

switch AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().recordPermission() {
case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.granted:
    print("Permission granted")
case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.denied:
    print("Pemission denied")
case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.undetermined:
    print("Request permission here")
    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission({ (granted) in
        // Handle granted
    })
}
```

for Objective-C ==>

```
#include <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

-(void)askForMicrophonePermission {
switch ([[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] recordPermission]) {
    case AVAudioSessionRecordPermissionGranted:
        break;
    case AVAudioSessionRecordPermissionDenied:
        break;
    case AVAudioSessionRecordPermissionUndetermined:
        // This is the initial state before a user has made any choice
        // You can use this spot to request permission here if you want
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]requestRecordPermission:^(BOOL granted) {
            // Check for granted
        }];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

}

Let me know if you still can't do it.

Answer (score 3):

for ios you have to set permission in info.plist file

```
 <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
 <string>${PRODUCT_NAME} always microphone use</string>
```

After add this permission , checking the microphone's current state on code file

```
switch AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().recordPermission() {
case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.granted:
print("Permission granted")
case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.denied:
print("Pemission denied")
case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.undetermined:
print("Request permission here")
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission({ (granted) in
    // Handle granted
})
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to explicitly ask for permission to use microphone. The app will do it automatically when you first try use audio input. The prerequisite is that you have `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` in your `info.plist`, otherwise the app will crash.

Alternatively, you may ask for permission earlier by calling `requestRecordPermission` method of `AVAudioSession`, but that is not necessary, and according to [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/app-architecture/requesting-permission/) you should ask for the use of personal data only when your app clearly needs it.